# Django doesn't detect the model I try to create

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I'm beginning (again) with django (1.7.5).

I've created :

- a project named "**hypnose**".
- an app named "**main**".
- a model named "**Article**".
- a superuser.

I've done enough code to make my application work, I can open the admin pannel, navigate through pages...
But when I try to create my database, Article model isn't detected by django (I've tried with syncdb, migrate and makemigrations) : Django just acts like the models simply doesn't exists!
I don't really know where the problem comes from, and I don't know if it comes from something I forgot, or if it is related to the new features of django 1.7 (with all the migration stuff I don't really understand).

Here are my source files :

**main/models.py :**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField(null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False,
    verbose_name = "Date de parution")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"%s" % (self.title,))

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s" % (self.title,))
```

**main/admin.py :**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import Article

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Article)
```

**admin.autodiscover()** is enabled in **hypnose.urls.py**.

It could be something really stupid but I'm stuck here since this morning. Did I forget something?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you add the `main` app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: No, I forgot that, indeed. Now I fixed that and everything works fine. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I will just add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you added the `main` app to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 12):

Another required item is to have a `migrations` directory and the file `__init__.py` inside it.

Comment: In my case, it was the missing `__init__.py` file. Thanks a lot!